# Agile Deployment + Git for ASP.NET / PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, version-control, setup-deployment

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a server that uses a GIT repo to deploy a server.  Our servers here are edited on the remote server and I am trying to set up the process to manage a deploy to our IIS servers.  Local > Development > Staging > Production using GIT for ASP.NET and PHP.

The other solutions I found were mainly PHP/Ruby specific.  I want to know if there is anything out there for ASP.NET and PHP.  I am trying to create a server that has everything centralized for deployment and source control.  They don't have to be one in the same program.     And a plus if it has a GUI.

I'm looking for alternative solutions and we currently use :
http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go-agile-release-management

Anyone have any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's one that does it for both. There's appharbor for .net.
https://appharbor.com/page/how-it-works

and for php there's phpfog
https://phpfog.com/why

Comment: Thanks.  However, a cloud solution is not an option for me =[.  I'm hoping to find some application to install onto the local servers here since all 3 servers are hosted in house.  Is there one for PHP and another for ASP.NET?  

It would be great to have some alternatives in mind also if the single solution for all does not work.